# Why does Apollo fail to build in Xcode - There can only be one fragment named ...?

Tags: xcode, apollo

Using:

- Xcode 10.1
- Apollo 1.9.2
- CocoaPods 1.5.3
- Latest build phase script from Apollo

During Xcode's build phase, when it executes the Apollo GraphQL API script, I get errors for duplicate fragments and operations, a-la:

```
"There can only be one fragment named..."
```

or

```
"There can only be one operation named..."
```

and the project will refuse to build.

Cleaning the build folder will allow you to build or run the project once more before the errors come back.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the bash `find` command is finding duplicate files in a local `DerivedData/` directory! This is caused when:

- You have the `DerivedData/` directory set to `Relative` in Xcode
- You're using the default build phase script provided by Apollo

---

Change your build phase script for Apollo from this:

`$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh codegen:generate --queries="$(find . -name '*.graphql')" --schema=schema.json API.swift`

to this:

`$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh codegen:generate --queries="$(find . -name '*.graphql'  -not -path "*DerivedData/*")" --schema=schema.json API.swift`

---

The Details:

- If you don't care where your Derived Data goes, change the Location setting from `Relative` to `Default` (or any directory Apollo is not looking in). You can find the setting here: *Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Derived Data*
- If you would rather keep your Derived Data where it is, alter the bash find command in the query passed to apollo-cli to exclude the `DerivedData/` folder by appending `-not -path "*DerivedData/*"`. You can find the script by going to *Project Root > (Target Project) > Build Phases > Generate Apollo GraphQL API*, (which you should have added during the installation steps, see [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation.html#adding-build-step)). Make it look like this:
  `$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh codegen:generate --queries="$(find . -name '*.graphql'  -not -path "*DerivedData/*")" --schema=schema.json API.swift`

You might need to delete the `DerivedData/` folder one last time from your project folder, and it doesn't hurt to do one last clean (`Command + Shift + K`).